# Spring Boot path variable validation does not work even in simplest project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

It's weird. I'm implementing even the simplest project with path variable validation and validation not works.

I have that rest controller:

```
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyController {


    @GetMapping("/student/{age}")
    ResponseEntity<String> student(@PathVariable("age") @Valid @Min(5) int age) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Your age is " + age);
    }
}
```

my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and returns always this Your age is age , no matter what I input as an age so @Min validation does not work.

I uploaded also pom.xml maybe this will be useful.

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: check out this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation

Comment: I do not like tutorials from Baeldung. Besides I want to pass variable in url not in body, as GET request not POST. I was trying this tutiorial, also seems legit https://www.yawintutor.com/how-to-validate-path-variable-in-spring-boot/

Comment: It is freshly created project in Intellij Idea, so I guess it downloads the latest and the newest things to the project.

Comment: I tried that also. I changed a letter that returns this method so changes happen

Comment: Can you post complete pom.xml for this app and complete application.properties?

Comment: Ok, I added in main post my pom.xml, application.properties are empty.

Comment: Thanks. Created a new project and pasted in content from your pom. Validation is still working on my computer. I think this case is not reprodusable. You should try to do it all over again.

Comment: But I was already trying it twice. First in my main bigger project wasn;t validation working. Now in this simple project it does not work. How many times do I need to start over?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `import` are correct and **try again.**

```java
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/student/{age}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> student(@PathVariable("age") @Min(5) int age) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Your age is " + age);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I did it.

I needed to change dependency from:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

then in application.properties add those lines:

```
server.error.include-message=always
server.error.include-binding-errors=always
```

Thanks for everybody that tried to help!

Comment: This case is an edge case, and this ad-hoc solution should not be followed by anyone else.

Comment: Doesn't work in Spring Boot 3

Answer (score 0):

This may not address the issue for Spring Boot 2.x, but I ran into the issue with Spring Boot 3.2 and had to correct the imports to:

```
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Min;
```

My validation test didn't error on javax imports, but also didn't validate until I corrected them to use jakarta.